# Web Essentials 2017 not showing up in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, web-essentials

I've installed Web Essentials 2017. When I open Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, it shows as being an installed extension, and "Reset Web Essentials" shows on the tools menu, but there are no settings that I can see. Shouldn't a settings dialog box be available somewhere?

Also, I thought if I create a .less file, open it, then save it, .css and .min.css files should immediately show up below the less file. That doesn't happen.

Additionally, the Web Essentials toolbar doesn't appear in Edge when I run a website from within Visual Studio. Hitting Ctrl doesn't make it appear.

What's going on here? Looks like Web essentials didn't install correctly and isn't working.

Comment: Web Essentials has been split up into multiple smaller packages. The Less functionality you're looking for is now part of the Web Compiler extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler The WebEssentials extension will try to download and install this other extension among it's friends, but if you're blocked behind a firewall it may not be able to download it and you may have to install it yourself. The full list of extensions can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017

Comment: According to this link, that extension is included as part of the full install:

https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2017

Comment: It's downloaded in the background after restarting visual studio.

Comment: Is there a way I can see which "sub-extensions" were installed successfully? Although it seems like something bigger is going on than just the Web Compiler extension not getting installed.

Comment: The manage extension s windows, they should get listed like any other extensions.

Comment: It just shows "Web Essentials 2017." They're not listed individually.

Comment: Then you'll need to install them manually or try what happens when you in install web essentials, reinstall it then restart vs twice.

Answer (score 6):

Clicking `Tools->Reset Web Essentials` fixed it. It looks like that just reinstalls it. Although I had already uninstalled and reinstalled, this worked.

There still doesn't appear to be an overall Web Essentials settings dialog box under tools. It appears that since it was broken up into individual components rather than one huge plugin, each plugin has its own little popup menu now, and a few of them show up when you right click on the Project.

Comment: Confirmed for VS2017 Enterprise v 15.2 (26430.15). I don't think it was necessary for earlier builds. I had to repair my VS installation and so reinstall the extensions and ran into this.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: There is no such menu item showing for me in VS2017 15.9.0

Comment: I have the same issue with VS2017 Community. I have uninstalled the WebPack Task runner from Nuget, and then Reinstalled it using Tools -> Extensions and Updates. After restarting VS I cant see ANYTHING to do with webpack. I am trying to compile some SCSS files and there is no WebPack tool or menu Item visible anywhere in my IDE....

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2017/issues/12) it was removed for few reasons. To fix it you have to download the [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-essentials/mghdcdlpcdiodelbplncnodiiadljhhk) and also download the [Browser Link Inspector](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserLinkInspector2017)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with extension downloaded from the web.

So i installed it from the marketplace and it works just fine.