# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise : Web Essential 2017 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2017, web-essentials

I have installed the VS 2017 Enterprise but still having trouble to understand why Web Essential tools 2017 not working in my installed IDE. It's appearing in the Tools menu as "Reset Web Essential". Except this nothing is working let say the simple AddFile extension packed with it! when go to Tools->options nothing about it is here!
i already have restored my VS uninstalling Resharper ultimate but still nothing!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Essentials 2017 not showing up in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763235/web-essentials-2017-not-showing-up-in-vs-2017)